# sigma/quadtree.insertNode: At least 5 nodes are outside the global quadtree zone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quadtree, sigma.js, graphology

I have created sigma js graph with original view and other with force atlas view but when I do something like drag node or click of node on original view and switch to force atlas view the graph completely breaks.

and gives waring like -sigma/quadtree.insertNode: At least 5 nodes are outside the global quadtree zone. You might have a problem with the normalization function or the custom bounding box.

How can this be mitigated, so that I can guarantee it to work every time.

This warning completely breaks the graph.

Sigma.js version: Latest
Graphology version: Latest
Operating System: Windows 11
Web browser: Chrome Latest

If needed a reproducible example can be supplied.

Cheers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.